# Importing mio::tcp::TcpStream but get std::net::tcp::TcpStream

Tags: rust, mio

In trying to adapt an [example server](https://github.com/dpc/mioecho), not sure what to make of this behaviour where the `TcpStream` I'm asking for and the one I'm getting appear to be entirely different.

Example struct definition:

```
use mio::tcp::TcpStream;

struct Connection {
    socket: TcpStream
}
```

Later there's a function defined for `Connection`:

```
fn writable(&mut self, event_loop: &mut EventLoop<Server>) -> Result<()> {
    loop {
        let (len, res) = {
            let buf = &self.buffer.bytes();
            let len = buf.len();
            let res = self.socket.write_slice(buf);
            (len, res)
        };
```

An error on `write_slice` shows up with:

```
error: type `std::net::tcp::TcpStream` does not implement any method in scope named `write_slice`
```

Now `std::net::tcp::TcpStream` doesn't implement this, but the [`mio::tcp::TcpStream`](https://carllerche.github.io/mio/mio/tcp/struct.TcpStream.html) does. Why would one get substituted for the other?

Setting this as an alias, `use mil::tcp::TcpStream as MioTcpStream` doesn't affect this either.

Comment: Do you have a `use std::net::tcp::TcpStream;` anywhere in your project?

Comment: Not anywhere I know of. If I include that the compiler complains about conflicting `TcpStream` definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem with the published version of the `mio` package.

Adding the following to `Cargo.toml` pulls down and uses the latest working version:

```
[dependencies.mio]
git = "https://github.com/carllerche/mio.git"
```